# Adding slide down effect for more than one element on the same page

Tags: jquery, slide

I'm trying to add the slide down effect for more than one div on the same page but only one at one time here is my code so far :

```
$(function(){
    $(".child").hide();
    $(".parent").hover(
        function(){ $(".child").slideDown('slow'); },
        function(){ $(".child").slideUp('slow'); }
    );

});
```

and the html

```
<div class="parent">
    <strong>This would display some content that I can click on</strong> 
</div>
<div class="child">
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom<br/>
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom<br/>
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom<br/>
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom<br/>
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom<br/>
</div>
```

```
<div class="parent">
    <strong>This would display some content that I can click on</strong> 
</div>
<div class="child">
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom<br/>
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom<br/>
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom<br/>
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom<br/>
    This expands across the whole window and is fixed to the bottom<br/>
</div>
```

problem is i want only one div to slide at a time not all

Answer (score 0):

You can try : [jQuery UI - Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$(".parent").hover(
        function(){ $(this).next(".child").slideDown('slow'); },
        function(){ $(this).next(".child").slideUp('slow'); }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:first` and `:last` to select one at a time and open it.

Thanks..